# How do I enable keyboard/mouse + controller at the same time?

Tags: controllers, destiny-2

I like putting a controller near me so I know when the controller is vibrating during cutscenes - as developers usually put in custom vibrations to match what's going on in the cutscene.
However, Destiny 2 does not do this. As soon as I use keyboard/mouse, the controller falls silent. Is there any way to enable this?

Comment: I believe they're mutually exclusive. Using the controller swaps the control set to controller and vice versa, like most games.

Comment: nope, a LOT of games(for eg metal gear solid 5,overwatch) let you use both input methods at the same time

Comment: Perhaps it's not setup for Fallen players who have four arms?

Comment: @DavidYell nice joke but using controllers and mice at the same time is a well known use case, for eg navigating menus in destiny is way faster on kb/m but controller feels better coz of force feedback. also there is the case of people who have less than five fingers on their hands using the controller + kb/m for stuff

Comment: Have you tried pressing a button on the controller at the beginning of a cutscene?

Comment: @ChaseSandmann i have not, does it enable both?

Comment: Vibrations definitely work if you switch between the two schemes.  I theorize that an input on the controller right before or during the cutscene will switch the input mode to "controller" which will enable the vibrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. I tried it out the other night, and as I suspected using either control set will swap the controls over exclusively to that set.

Comment: yeah it's pretty much a dev only fix

Answer (score 0):

Its not a completely easy task and may be to late to help now (my answer) but you can have both Keyboard / Controller support through specialist third party programs that enable key binding and re-mapping of the controller.

This will allow you to re-map controller to keyboard and mouse while also using the keyboard and mouse when desired. The problem is that Destiny 2 has a go stop approach to the recognition of controller be it either on or off and its not an easy trick to disable the controller recognition while having it active and fully functional.

Currently another third party support and some file tinkering is needed to disable controller support from Destiny 2 this in turn will enable the controller player to use other software that will allow for the remapping. 
In this case the purpose is for vibration to be active, this will not be the case as vibration is not associated with keyboard and mouse functionality once the controller is remapped.

Here is where I'm up to as all the software I have come across is inferior in some way shape or form causing the utilization of a string of software to get / receive the desired effect of remapped buttons / vibration support and in my case a simple toggle when holding forward on the controller for run instead of wrecking my pad utilizing the left thumb-stick button as a sprint toggle.

Know I'm trying to get with all this software already utilized Destiny 2 running through steam where a function exists that again can re-enable a controller but within some additional set parameters (not completely functional but what you choose). If I get this to work then I will have a hi-breed controller that has the best of both worlds. Good thing is is that Destiny 2 is not going to the EPIC launcher but to steam sooner rougher then later so this in turn may help address some controller functionality issues that the developers are really slow on what seems never to be responded too.

Controller support on games like APEX Legends with their Advance Look Controls are second to none and at the very least especially with the influx of cross saved players to PC additional controller functionality and support should be looked into and further developed for the good of the game with games like Apex considered in this needed approach. Like for gods sake how about two varying sensitivity gauges at the least for hip fire and ADS'ing (which currently does not exist for controller players only keyboard and mouse and this is easily done.).